# Prove that $ u_1 + u_5 = 2u_3 $.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

$u_n$ is an arithmetic progression which is an increasing sequence.

Prove that $$ u_1 + u_5 = 2u_3 $$

is it correct to rely on the law that states that $a + c = 2b$.

Comment: What's the definition of an arithmetic sequence?

Comment: Easier I think to just do it from scratch.  The terms are $u_1, u_1+d, u_1+2d, u_1+3d, u_1+4d$ after all.

Comment: What are $a$ and $c$?

Answer (score 3):

$u_5 = u_1 + 4d$

$u_3 = u_1 + 2d$

So $u_1 + u_5 = 2u_1 + 4d = 2(u_1 + 2d) = 2u_3$